# Why vkGetInstanceProcAddr() fails for extension functions?

Tags: windows, vulkan

I am able to get pointers to all Vulkan core functions, but getting a pointer to a Vulkan extension functions fails.

First I get a pointer to `vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddr()`, and with it I get pointers to global Vulkan functions (e.g. `vkCreateInstance()`). I enable `VK_KHR_surface` and `VK_KHR_win32_surface` extensions at instance creation, and they are listed as supported by vulkaninfo.exe and `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties()`. After creating a Vulkan instance, I get pointers to all instance functions with `vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddr()` and the instance handle. However, when trying to get a pointer to `vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR()` for example, a null pointer is returned. Same happens with `vkDestroySurfaceKHR()`.

I have Nvidia drivers 356.39 installed with Vulkan API 1.0.3 support. Am I doing something wrong?

The code:

```
// Gets vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddr() from the driver DLL
vkGetInstanceProcAddr = getLibraryFunction("vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddr");

vkCreateInstance = vkGetInstanceProcAddr(nullptr, "vkCreateInstance");

const std::array<const char*, 2u> extensionNames
{
    "VK_KHR_surface",
    "VK_KHR_win32_surface"
};

VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceInfo = VkInstanceCreateInfo();
instanceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
instanceInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensionNames.size());
instanceInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensionNames.data();

VkInstance instanceHandle;
vkCreateInstance(&instanceInfo, nullptr, &instanceHandle);

// Returns a non-null pointer
vkCreateDevice = vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instanceHandle, "vkCreateDevice");

// Returns a null pointer
vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR = vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instanceHandle, "vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR");
```

Comment: "*Gets vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddr() from the driver DLL*" Any reason you're getting the driver DLL's pointer directly, rather than just using what you already have?

Comment: Because I already have nothing. I'm not using any 3rd party code or libraries.

Comment: I think they mean that the function is in [vulkan.h](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/xhtml/vkspec.html#vkGetInstanceProcAddr) and you don't need to query the dll for it.

Comment: Afaik there's no (static) library to link vulkan.h function declarations with. [Khronos' Vulkan reference loader](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/master/loader/LoaderAndLayerInterface.md) also links the declarations with the driver DLL.

Comment: Are you using vulkan-1.lib from the [lunag SDK](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/signin)? That has the entry point you want

Comment: No, I'm not using any 3rd party code or libraries. I'm doing everything from scratch for learning and experimenting.

Comment: @Devenec: It is difficult to call the official Vulkan loader "3rd party".

Comment: @NicolBolas By 3rd party code I meant code I have not written by myself. Sorry if I used misleading terms.

Comment: @Devenec "code I have not written", cool, so why are you even using Vulkan? just write you're own graphics API...

Comment: Isn't this more a question about why you insist on using the dynamic library (and thus need to query for the function adresses) instead of just linking statically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, getting the pointers to extension functions works fine (e.g. for `vkCreateSwapchainKHR()`). If I examined the code of [Khronos' Vulkan reference loader](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers) correctly, the implementations of [`vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR()`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/master/loader/wsi.c#L480) and [`vkDestroySurfaceKHR()`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/master/loader/wsi.c#L208) are not provided by the driver, but by the loader.